# Game Center do not connect in Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, game-center

I made an app that use `Game Center` and
this is the code I added to the file:

```
func authenticateLocalPlayer(){

    var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController, error) -> Void in

        if (viewController != nil) {
            self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        else {
            println((GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated))
            println(error)
        }
    }

}

func showLeader() {
    var vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
    var gc = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gc.gameCenterDelegate = self
    vc?.presentViewController(gc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//hides leaderboard screen
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!)
{
    gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
func saveHighscore(score:Int) {

    //check if user is signed in
    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated {

        var scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "countrymasterlbid20151993") //leaderboard id here

        scoreReporter.value = Int64(score) //score variable here (same as above)

        var scoreArray: [GKScore] = [scoreReporter]

        GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: {(error : NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println("error")
            }
        })

    }

}

@IBAction func gc(sender: AnyObject) {
    saveHighscore(score)
    showLeader()
}
```

in the `ViewDidLoad` fund I added this code:

```
authenticateLocalPlayer()
```

When I run the `simulator` It doesn't show me the `connection view` and the `error` message is:

> Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=2 "The requested operation has been
>   canceled or disabled by the user." UserInfo=0x7fcee382af30
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=The requested operation has been canceled or
>   disabled by the user.}

Comment: That message appears when the user cancelled the GameCenter sign in too many times in a row (i think 3).  From there you need to manually sign in through the Settings app

Comment: @DavidSkrundz Well I tried from the settings and it works! but when I click on the button 'gc' i get this error: 
`2015-08-05 16:52:23.052 refreshing[6735:226265] Warning: Attempt to present <GKGameCenterViewController: 0x7fde2c03d9f0> on <refreshing.ViewController: 0x7fde29e1c460> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
2015-08-05 16:52:25.352 refreshing[6735:226265] Warning: Attempt to present <refreshing.gameOver: 0x7fde2c04f150> on <refreshing.ViewController: 0x7fde29e1c460> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`